# Adding multiple unique attribute in the custom policy

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

Is there any way to add the phone number + email address to be unique in the custom field while signup the page for example +911234567890  sample@gmail.com the combination of this two is always unique in the b2c.

Comment: If you are storing the emailAddress which is used for B2C login in custom field than you don't need to worry about uniqueness. Registration can only be happen if email address is not present in B2C.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement the check with a custom Validation Technical profile based on a RESTful TP (i.e an Azure Function). You can pass the phone number and the email as input claims, query the Microsoft Graph API and if you find a user with that phone number and that email you should return a 409 Conflict response (so the user journey can't proceed). A 200 OK otherwise.